# Picking a bluetooth module

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth

I've recently acquired a lpc1313fbd48 microcontroller and I was looking around on newark.com for a bluetooth module that I could use to connect my microcontroller with my phone. I then began to if certain microcontrollers can accept certain bluetooth modules.

So my question is:
How do I pick a bluetooth module for my microcontroller? Are there certain pins or frequencies that I should be aware of when searching for a module?

Comment: What's communicated over BT, and what for?

Comment: @NickAlexeev Changing the music on an iPhone or android

Comment: You will need to be a member of Apple's MFi program (difficult) to change the music on an iPhone. There are a few bluetooth modules that have the iAP (iPod accessory protocol) profile supported.

Comment: @Coder404, Ive heard that making an application on iphone which involves bluetooth is much complicated than that for android. Althought I have never made an app for iphone but for Android any bluetooth module would work for sure. I used RN52 from Roving Networks

Answer (score 1):

BT modules usually have at least one of the following interfaces: UART serial (most common), SPI, I<sup>2</sup>C.  These interfaces are standard, and agnostic with respect to controller brand and model.  LPC1313 (which was mentioned in the O.P.) has all of these interfaces.

**P.S.** For something like a BT remote for changing music on Androind, consider looking for modules, which can support Human Interface Device profile (HID, [graphic details here](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/bluetooth/technology/profiles.html)).

Comment: @Coder404  You're welcome.  Let us know what you choose

Comment: There are some really cheap Chinese Bluetooth modules available from [Itead](http://imall.iteadstudio.com/wireless/bluetooth-and-zigbe/im120723009.html) and on Ebay (search for bluetooth hc-05). Itead have a datasheet. These are serial (38400) connected modules with an AT command set.